# Why is the variable still tied

Tags: perl, scope, tie

Running:

```
$t =  3;
{
    tie $t, 'Yep';
} # Expect $t to become untied here.
print $t;

package Yep;

sub TIESCALAR {
   bless {}, 'Yep';
}

sub UNTIE {
   print "UNTIE\n";
}

sub DESTROY {
   print "DESTROY\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
Can't locate object method "FETCH" via package "Yep" at a.pl line 5.
DESTROY
```

The EXPECTED output is:

```
DESTROY
3
```

I want to `tie` variable $t only for the duration of the scope in which `tie` is located. Out of the scope it must behave same as before tie. So I wrap `tie` into the block and expect that `untie` will be called when the end of block is reached (like 'local' where the value is restored at the end of block, but for tied variable I expect behaviour is restored (`untie $t`) ). Notice the `$t` is not out of scope yet.

Comment: [Cross-posted on perl5porters](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2015/10/msg231557.html). Zefram's answer: 'That is intentionally not how tying behaves. Tying effects a permanent
change to the object in question, in this case the scalar $t, and the
effect lasts as long as the object does.  It is no more lexically scoped
than the effect of "$t = 4" inside the block would be.'

Comment: Also, as a side note, please don't completely change your question after you've received answers. You invalidate the existing answers and make things confusing for future visitors, since some answers will address your new question and some answers will address the old, completely different question. In the future, please just ask a new question.

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not think it is so different. I think tie/untie work in same manner like: new/delete, inc/dec, create/destroy. So at the end of file scope (when program end) I expect variable to be untied and DESTROY is called for object constructed at TIESCALAR. So instead of implicit file scope I create explicit around 'tie ...' @ThisSuitIsBlackNot

Comment: The question is quite different: witness ikegami's two distinct answers.

Comment: As for your repeated assertion that `tie` should use dynamic scoping like `local`, that's just not how it works, no matter how hard you may wish it so. I don't follow your point about new/delete, inc/dec, etc. delete: `$h{foo} = 1; { delete $h{foo} } say for keys %h`; increment: `{ $i++ } say $i`; new: `package Foo; sub new { bless { foo => $_[1] }, $_[0] } package main; $foo = Foo->new(0); { $foo = Foo->new(1) } say $foo->{foo}`. None of the changes made inside the block are reverted outside of the block. Maybe you should explain exactly why you want this behavior.

Comment: Your comments give me the clue! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the completely new question,

Changes to variables aren't automatically undone when the scope in which those changes are made

```
my $t = 3;

{
   $t = 4;
}

print "$t\n";  # 4, not 3.
```

Same goes when the change is to add tie magic. You can use `untie` to remove the magic, but it's best if you simply use a new variable.

```
my $t = 3;

{
   tie my $t, 'Yep';
} # Tied variable destroyed here.

print "$t\n";  # 3.
```

Comment: Does 'local' be better than 'my'?

Comment: You never want to use `local`. You only use it when you can't use `my`

Answer (score 4):

> **Answering:** Why is UNTIE not called when tied variable goes out of scope?

Because `UNTIE` handles when the user calls the builtin [`untie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/untie.html) command. If it calls `DESTROY` when going out of scope, handle `DESTROY`.

If you need logic in both then you can

1. Call a common cleanup sub from both

   ```
   sub UNTIE   { &_destructor; } # Perl 4 style, which passes the current
   sub DESTROY { &_destructor; } # @_ to the called procedure.
   ```
2. `goto` common cleanup sub from both

   ```
   sub UNTIE   { goto &_destructor; } # does not return to this sub
   sub DESTROY { goto &_destructor; } # does not return to this sub
   ```
3. *Alias* one to the other:

   ```
   *UNTIE = *DESTROY{CODE};
   ```

Comment: #2 is purely worse than #1. It's slower, and it makes debugging harder by messing up the stack trace.

Answer (score 4):

> *Why is UNTIE not called when tied variable goes out of scope?*

Asking why `UNTIE` isn't called when the variable goes out of scope is the same thing as asking why `UNTIE` isn't called whenever `DESTROY` is called. Well, that would be useless. What is useful is a function that's called when `untie` is called, and that's what `UNTIE` is.

If you want common code to be called when `untie` is called and when the object is destroyed, nothing's stopping you.

```
sub UNTIE   { shift->_destructor(@_) }
sub DESTROY { shift->_destructor(@_) }
```

Comment: No, I exactly mean UNTIE

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, I don't understand your comment. I clarified my answer in case it helps.

Comment: I clarified my question

Answer (score 0):

The example with **my** give me a clue. So in my case use local.

```
my $t = 3;

{
   tie local $t, 'Yep';
} # Tied variable destroyed here.

print "$t\n";  # 3.
```